# How to check, if Terraform will create resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, hcl

I use Terraform + AWS Lambda in my workflow, and i want to call some lambda with ARNs of my existent instances during every plan or apply action. I use this structure:

```
locals {
   ...
   centralized_nodes = {...}
   tags_map = {...}

   backup_map = {        
   for node in keys(local.centralized_nodes):
   node => aws_instance.centralized_node[node].arn
   if can(local.tags_map[node]["backup"]) && !(can(aws_instance.centralized_node[node].root_block_device.0.tags["backup"]))
   }
   ...
}
resource "aws_instance" "centralized_node" {
    ...
    for_each                 = local.centralized_nodes
    ...
}
data "aws_lambda_invocation" "lambda_backup" {
  for_each = local.backup_map  
  function_name = "lambdafunc"
  input = jsonencode({          
        "resources"            = [each.value]         
    })
}
```

it worked fine until i try to add node description object to `centralized_nodes` map and create new instance. When i add this, terraform shows me error during planning:

```
Error: Invalid for_each argument
│ 
│   on resources.tf line 223, in data "aws_lambda_invocation" "lambda_backup":
│  223:   for_each = local.backup_map  
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.backup_map will be known only after apply
│ 
│ The "for_each" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created. To work around this, use the
│ -target argument to first apply only the resources that the for_each depends on.
```

Now i'm looking for terraform check if resource exists or will be created. i've tried adding arguments to map generator to exclude uncreated instances (it's OK in my workflow) like that:

```
if can(local.tags_map[node]["backup"]) && !(can(aws_instance.centralized_node[node].root_block_device.0.tags["backup"])) && can(aws_instance.centralized_node[node].arn)
```

But it doesn't work, terraform thinks it can reach ARN value for uncreated instance, but later.

Please, help me find the way to avoid such error.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It very much looks like you are trying to use Terraform for something it was not meant to be used for. Why not use the AWS CLI in your scripts to invoke the Lambdas before you run your Terraform. Keep it simple.

Comment: I use AWS snapshot backup functions based on ebs volume tags. This part of code should autoheal backup volume tags if they were broken. Also I can't attach these tags using terraform, because they contain instance and volume IDs, that why i use Lambdas for tags management.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your `local.centralized_nodes` is not pre-defined by rather generated automatically. If so, you [can't use it](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html) with `for_each`.

> The keys of the map (or all the values in the case of a set of strings) **must be known values**, or you will get an error message that for_each has dependencies that cannot be determined before apply, and a -target may be needed.

You can try converting your code to use `count`, as `count` does not have such a limitation. But then, `count` has its own issues which may prevent you from achieving your goals anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the only one way to get check if resources like instances and volumes already exist. It is using aws_instance and aws_instances datasources.
This is my solution:

```
locals {
   ...
   centralized_nodes = {...}
   tags_map = {...}
   instance_name_root_volume_tags_map = {
        for name, value in {for id, value in data.aws_instance.instance_id_arn_map : value.tags["Name"] => value}:
        name => data.aws_ebs_volume.volume_instance_id_map[value.id].tags
   } 
   backup_map = {        
   for name, value in {for id, value in data.aws_instance.instance_id_arn_map : value.tags["Name"] => value}:
        name => value.arn
        if !can(local.instance_name_root_volume_tags_map[name]["backup"]) && can({for node, value in local.tags_map: value["Name"] => value}[name]["backup"]) )
   }
   ...
}
resource "aws_instance" "centralized_node" {
    ...
    for_each                 = local.centralized_nodes
    ...
}
data "aws_lambda_invocation" "lambda_backup" {
  for_each = local.backup_map  
  function_name = "lambdafunc"
  input = jsonencode({          
        "resources"            = [each.value]         
    })
}
data "aws_instances" "existant_instances_array" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values =  [for tagmap in local.hiera_tags_map : tagmap["Name"]] 
  }
}
data "aws_instance" "instance_id_arn_map" {
  for_each  = toset(data.aws_instances.existant_instances_array.ids)
  instance_id = each.value
}
data "aws_ebs_volume" "volume_instance_id_map" {
  for_each  = data.aws_instance.instance_id_arn_map
  filter {
      name = "attachment.instance-id"
      values = [each.value.id]
  }
  filter {
      name = "attachment.device"
      values = ["/dev/sda1"]
  }
}
```